# approximate the solution $x=2$ using newton's method for $P(x)=-1536+6272x-11328x^2+11872x^3-7952x^4+3528x^5-1036x^6+194x^7-21x^8+x^9$

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I need help with this excercise.

I know that $x=2$ is a solution for
$$P(x)=-1536+6272x-11328x^2+11872x^3-7952x^4+3528x^5-1036x^6+194x^7-21x^8+x^9$$

I want aproximate the solution $x=2$ using newton method, but, I dont know what happen.
for any initial value using mathlab or python it jumps me to solutions 3 or 4 (solutions too),
example for $x=2,000000004$

[image]

Is it possible to solve this problem?

Im sorry for my English.

---

Plot: (zoom)
[image]

Comment: Did you look at the plot? That might explain things. Try $x_0 = -5.0$

Comment: The big jump from 0 to 1 shows that there is something wrong.  Are you sure x=2 is a root?

Comment: Do you want the basin of attraction that does lead to 2 eventually? Or do you just want the explanation for why something close to one root can overshoot and converge to some totally different root?

Comment: For a more analytic view, the polynomial factors as $(x-2)^7 (x-3) (x-4)$.
Thus the polynomial is very flat at $x =  2$ and so if you apply a single iteration of Newton's method it will take you somewhere far away.

Comment: Yes, the text say, $x=2$ is a root, I added the graph

Comment: Use a higher order Newton Method for multiple roots because you have a seventh order root at $x = 2$.

Comment: @Moo that idea works, although how would someone know that's a 7th-order root without the factorization?

Comment: I always plot it first - because that would have identified the issue instantly.

Comment: @MichaelLugo You can compute the derivatives of $P(x)$ at $x=2$... It will be zero up to the sixth order.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to learn is how to "peel off" or factor out roots you don't want.

Suppose you apply Newton's Method seeking roots of $f(x)=0$ and you find $x=\xi_1$ as a root that you want to factor out. Therefore you now want to apply the method to $f(x)/(x-\xi_1)=0$ with the idea that you knock out the $\xi_1$ root and force convergence elsewhere.

Apply the recursion to the modified function:

$x_{n+1}=x_n-\dfrac{f(x_n)/(x-\xi_1)}{(d/dx)(f(x_n)/(x-\xi_1))@x=x_n}$

When you apply the quotient rule to the derivative in the denominator you find that a factor of $1/(x-\xi_1)$ cancels, giving a simpler recursive form:

$x_{n+1}=x_n-\dfrac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)-f(x_n)/(x_n-\xi_1)}$

Note that the remived root in this firm appears only as a modifying term in the denominator; the numerator remains the original function.

That is for factoring out one root. If you factor out more roots, that corresponds to more subtractions of $f(x_n)/(x-\xi_k)$ from the denominator, so your recursion with any number of removed roots takes the form

$x_{n+1}=x_n-\dfrac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)-f(x_n)\Sigma[1/(x_n-\xi_k)]}$

where the summation is over all the roots you remove.

In successive applications with removed roots you should tailor your initial guesses so that you are on the "right side" of the roots you have factored out. If you remove a root $x=3$ and you are aiming for a smaller root, then your next starting point after removing the $x=3$ root would be a smaller value than $3$.

Comment: Thank you very much, 
I am trying to implement this, but, with several iterations, it stays at values close to 2, it does not reach the value, like 2,00861802565511.